# PHP include_once adding trailing 1 to page

Tags: php, include

```
$num = 39; //sets number of weeks - there are only 38 rounds so 39 is fine
$num2 = $num-1; //for adding the previous weeks table - rest of code not added yet 

while($num > 0) // set to 0 so that when it reaches week 1 it stops
{
    if ( file_exists('./results/week'.$num.'.html'))  
    {
        echo '<h1>week '.$num.'</h1>';
        echo (include_once('./results/week'.$num.'.html'));
        $num = $num - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $num = $num - 1;
    }
}
```

Hi 
I'm trying to add a number of tables (html files) to a page and this code seems to work, however it adds a 1 to the end of each table so I get:

```
Week 3
Name  Result
John  4
Bob   3
1
Week 2
Name  Result
Bob   6
John  1
1
```

etc.
Could some kind soul please tell me where this 1 is coming from? And how to get rid of it?
I'd be most grateful.
Ta Rich

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't `echo include_once`, just `include_once`. The 1 is the `echo`ed return value of the `include_once` call.

Comment: That's very kind of you. I'm continually doing stupid stuff like this.

Answer (score 2):

the "true" boolean value converted as string, will become "1"

so the return of the include function call, that returns true by default,
will be converted to "1" when you echo it

so, don't echo include(); use just include();

---

another info, here is the correct usage of echo with include:

inc.php:

```
<?php return "hello there"; ?>
```

page.php:

```
<?php
 include("inc.php"); // no output here
 echo include("inc.php"); // hello, output!
?>
```

Comment: What if the inc.php is just "hello there" and the page.php is return include("inc.php"); For me, I still get the '1'

Answer (score 1):

include_once returns true, which equates to 1, so when you have echo (include_once...) you're actually putting in echo "1", so just use include_once.

Answer (score 0):

the 1 is the return value of the function include_once (yes, it is a function).

It will return true (1) if the file exists and false (0) if it does not exist.

So just don't echo the include_once and you're all done.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
   while($num > 0) // set to 0 so that when it reaches week 1 it stops
    {
    if ( file_exists('./results/week'.$num.'.html'))  
    {
    echo '<h1>week '.$num.'</h1>';
    include_once('./results/week'.$num.'.html');
    $num = $num - 1;
    }
    else
    {
    $num = $num - 1;
    }
    }
```

Don't echo include_once....

Answer (score 0):

if you call `<?= incluce_once();?>` the number 1 will be shown, because the short tag will represent an echo.

Experiment use `<?php incluce_once()?>`